# repeat a sequence of numbers N times and incrementally increase the values in the sequence Python

Tags: python, range, python-itertools

I have a number sequence as below

```
sequence = (0,0,1,1,1,1)
```

I want the number sequence to repeat a specified number of times but incrementally increase the values within the sequence

so if n= 3 then the sequence would go 1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,6,6,6,6

I can make a sequence like below but the range function is not quite right in this instance

```
n = 3
CompleteSequence =  [j + k for j in range(0, n, 2) for k in sequence]
CompleteSequence 
[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```

I have tried itertools

```
import itertools
sequence = (0,0,1,1,1,1)
n=3
list1 = list(itertools.repeat(sequence,n))
list1

[(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1), (0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1), (0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1)]
```

How can I go I achieve the pattern I need? a combination of range and itertools?

Comment: Does the initial sequence always only contain `1` and `0`?

Comment: @Unmitigated yes will always be 0,0,1,1,1,1. I could probably work with 1,1,2,2,2,2 then incrementing from there.  the incrementing pattern is what I am mainly trying to achieve

Comment: Why does it ***need*** to use itertools? It can be achieved using lost comprehensions instead.

Comment: @MatBailie it doesn't have to use itertools, that was just a method I was trying.

Comment: Only exactly 0,0,1,1,1,1? Not even for example 0,0,0,1,1?

Comment: And input is just the number n?

Comment: @KellyBundy yes the sequence is always 0,0,1,1,1,1. n is actually dynamically derived but I have used it as as  input to get help. there are few solutions below that achieved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### You **can** achieve this pattern with `range()` and an `increment` variable:

```
sequence = (0,0,1,1,1,1)
n = 3

CompleteSequence = []
increment = 1
for i in range(1, n+1):
    for j in sequence:
        CompleteSequence.append(j + increment)
    increment += 2
```

`CompleteSequence` now holds:

```
[1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
s = [0,0,1,1,1,1]
n = 3
r = [
  i + offset
    for offset in range(1, n*2+1, 2)
    for i in s
]
```

Demo : https://trinket.io/python3/3b1d5c0261

Answer (score 1):

You can also use:

```
from itertools import repeat

sequence = (0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1)
n = 3
list1 = [i*2+j+1 for i, s in enumerate(repeat(sequence, n)) for j in s]
print(list1)

# Output
[1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your "incrementally increase" and *"the incrementing pattern is what I am mainly trying to achieve"* sound like:

```py
from itertools import accumulate

incrementing_pattern = [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
n = 3

sequence = accumulate(n * incrementing_pattern)

print(*sequence)
```

Output ([Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3p6QV5ecqZJakFpXk5-cUK2TmFuQXlSgkJieX5pbmJJakcnFl5iUXpeam5pVk5qXHFySWANXmKdgqRBvqKBjoKEBIEIrlAgkbc3EVpxaWpuYlpwJ5CHM08hS0FLAZpcnFVVCUmVeioQXTpwlxG9SJMKcCAA)):

```
1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 4 4 4 4 5 5 6 6 6 6
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `range(start, stop, step)` - i.e. with `step=2` to only iterate over the *odd* values:

```py
>>> [[i] * 2 + [i + 1] * 4 for i in range(1, 6, 2)]
[[1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4], [5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6]]
```

Full example:

```
# they are the same
sequence = (0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1)
assert [0] * 2 + [1] * 4 == list(sequence)

n = 3

result = [[i] * 2 + [i + 1] * 4 for i in range(1, n * 2, 2)]
print(result)

# in the case you need to unpack values into one list
result = []
for i in range(1, n * 2, 2):
    result += [i] * 2 + [i + 1] * 4
print(result)
```

Result:

```py
[[1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4], [5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6]]
[1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6]
```